# stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, get, stream-socket-client

I want to access server data nginx server then i get this error:

> stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

please help me out how i can fix this issue.

that's my code that i can use to access data

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://example.com/api/v1' );
echo 'Response:<pre>'; 
print_r($response);
```